# How can I send data from the API to elastic search?

Tags: python, api, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to send the API data to Elastic Search and  use Lambda to pull data from API every x number of minutes? Do you know of any python code examples?

Comment: Codes in this link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-getting-started-python.html has all you need for sending data to elasticsearch using python. As for the second part of the question, well its all about the type of API request which you have not specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set-up a Lambda with CloudWatch as trigger (scheduled/cron job).
This will run your python lambda every x minute.

Pulling data from the API:

```
import requests
url = 'API url to pull data from.(string)'
params = 'Query Parameters.(dict)'
api_response = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
if api_response.status_code != 200:
  raise Exception('API call failed')
```

Sending data to elastic search (Example from the python ElasticSearch client)

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
resp = es.index(index="test-index", id=1, document=doc)
print(resp['result'])

resp = es.get(index="test-index", id=1)
print(resp['_source'])

es.indices.refresh(index="test-index")

resp = es.search(index="test-index", query={"match_all": {}})
print("Got %d Hits:" % resp['hits']['total']['value'])
for hit in resp['hits']['hits']:
    print("%(timestamp)s %(author)s: %(text)s" % hit["_source"])
```

you need these python modules installed

```
pip install elasticsearch
pip install requests
```